# How to notify user by email when timesheet is approuved with dynamics nav 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2010, dynamics-nav, dynamics-nav-2013

i work on Project that displays dynamics Nav 2013 timesheet in sharepoint 2010 With WebPart.

i want send email automaticly to user when timesheet is approuved by apporouver ?

thx

Answer (score 0):

You can use codeunit 400 to send e-mails through SMTP. 
But I think you wil need a developer license to achive this.

When you are allowed to write C/AL code with your license you should find out which report or codeunit is run to apporove the timesheet. And then add a function that sends a notification to the user.

Comment: If you are able to write c/al code please let me know, and I will help you with the code.